# Converting string array into integer array not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following array:

```
s = "215, 216, 217"
```

When I do

```
s.split(",").map(Number)
```

I am getting this back:

```
[NaN, 216, NaN]
```

If s has only two numbers, both return as NaN. Help!

**Update:**

Got it fixed! I had to get rid of quotes that surrounded the string because I was getting it from a cookie.

```
s.replace(/\"/g, "").split(",").map(Number)
```

did the trick!

Thanks!

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome, latest

Comment: cannot be reproduced in google chrome Version 34.0.1847.131

Comment: Actually, I am doing it through cookies and realized my array when I do `split(",")` on the string I get this: `[""215", " 216", " 217""] `

Comment: update your question?

Answer (score 1):

This will explains it:

```
s.split(",").map(function(item){ return item.trim() }).map(Number)
```

There are space between the numbers:

```
s = "215,/* here */ 216,/* here */ 217"
```

**Other possible solutions**

```
s.replace(/\s/g,'').split(',').map(Number)
```

or what it seems was the initial approach but using Regular Expression to get rid of the extra space:

```
s.split(/\s*,\s*/).map(Number)
```

Comment: I just realized because it's going through cookies, when I just do `.split(",")` I get this: `[""215", " 216", " 217""]`

Comment: Need to get rid of that surrounding quotes within the array

Comment: `s.split(",").map(function(item){ return item.match(/\d+/)})`

Comment: thanks @Ejay I was trying to make a point although your option is very valid. I was also thinking about s.replace(/\s/g,'').split(',').map(Number)

Comment: it seems @MohamedElMahallawy just did it in that way :)