# Splitting an array of strings to an array of floats in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, parsefloat

I am trying to split an array of strings, called 'vertices' and store it as an array of floats.

Currently the array of strings contains three elemets: `["0 1 0", "1 -1 0", '-1 -1 0"]`

What I need is an array of floats containing all these digits as individual elements: `[0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0]`

I used the split() function as follows:

```
for(y = 0; y < vertices.length; y++)
{
    vertices[y] = vertices[y].split(" "); 
}
```

...which gives me what looks to be what I am after except it is still made up of three arrays of strings.

How might I use parseFloat() with split() to ensure all elements are separate and of type float?

Comment: You want to [flatten](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10865025/218196) the array and [convert each element to a number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23457895/218196).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method for this:

```js
var result = ["0 1 0", "1 -1 0", "-1 -1 0"].reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.concat(curr.split(' ').map(Number));
}, []);

alert(result); // [0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0]
```

Instead of `.map(Number)` you can use `.map(parseFloat)` of course if you need.

Or even shorter:

```
var result = ["0 1 0", "1 -1 0", "-1 -1 0"].join(' ').split(' ').map(Number);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this.

```js
var res = []
for (var y = 0; y < vertices.length; y++) {
  var temp = vertices[y].split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    res.push(parseFloat(temp[i]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The other answer came just before you but this was also helpful! +1

Comment: In fact this answer is more generic so it should be accepted.

Comment: @petehallw how is this answer more generic…?

Comment: @royhowie kind of has a point. dfsq's solution when he started wasn't quite as good as mine, he didn't map the results to numbers. But after his edit it's just as generic of a solution, just seems more compact.

Comment: @Shriike You should probably add `var` keywords to `y` and `i` definitions.

Comment: @Shriike I didn't mean that your answer shouldn't've been accepted. I was just wondering why the OP thought your answer was more generic.

Comment: @royhowie that's fine, but I do think the other answer should have been accepted over mine :) I was just agreeing with you that the other answer is just as generic but more compact.